# How to merge multiple excel files using SQL with a query and not using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have 10 excel files with same data structure. Each file has first name and last name in Sheet1. But the file names are different and has no pattern in it. All the 10 files are present in a same folder.

I want to use SQL to merge all 10 files and get it into one SQL table. Is there a way to do that.

```
Files path: C:\User\ferguson\excelfiles

Excel file 1 : name.xlsx
Excel file 2: names.xlsx
Excel file 3: details.xlsx
.
.
.
.
Excel file 10: info.xlsx
```

I want one single SQL table with all the data in all files using a SQL QUERY. Can it be done using BULK Insert or something?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can write some c# code for this

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**`OPENROWSET`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [**`OPENDATASOURCE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) using a compliant ODBC driver or OLEDB provider that runs a `UNION` query across all workbooks. Below assumes each workbook has named columns named, `FirstName` and `LastName` starting in `A1` in worksheet named,`Sheet1`.

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
           DBQ=C:\Path\To\File1.xlsx', 
           'SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [Sheet1$]')

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
           DBQ=C:\Path\To\File2.xlsx', 
           'SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [Sheet1$]')
...

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
           DBQ=C:\Path\To\File10.xlsx', 
           'SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Alternatively, you can use a provider version:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
               'Data Source=C:\Path\To\File1.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...Sheet1$ 
...
```

Possibly you can even combine in one call, connecting to first workbook:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
           DBQ=C:\Path\To\File10.xlsx', 
           'SELECT [FirstName], [LastName] 
            FROM [Sheet1$]

            UNION ALL
            SELECT [FirstName], [LastName]
            FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\File2.xlsx].[Sheet1$]

            ...

            UNION ALL
            SELECT [FirstName], [LastName]
            FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\File10.xlsx].[Sheet1$]
          ')
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way where we can loop through all excel files in a folder and get the data in a single SQL table through a SQL query? What i see from the above code is we are giving the file names in the code. Instead I want SQL to loop through all excel files and retrieve data

Comment: Consider application layer/general-purpose language like C#, Java, Python, even Excel VBA to connect to database and iteratively append data from various workbooks through a directory. Such operations are much easier than within server databases that are not meant to traverse client operating systems' files and folders. Please do research on a solution and make an earnest attempt before asking. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Parfait suggested, or use VBA in Excel to get the job done.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\your_path_here"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, Python would do it, and R would concatenate all the files into one single file.  You could use C#.NET or VB.NET to do this kind of thing.  If you had a bunch of CSV files, or TXT files, you could loop through those, and do a BULK INSERT, but you can't do that with Excel files.